# Error using DWR with Grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails, dwr

I keep getting the same error with DWR on grails when I connect to the page that is using it:

```
2014-12-15 08:48:57,621 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] INFO  log.startup  - Starting: DwrServlet    v3.0.0-RC3-dev-574 on Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 / JDK 1.8.0_25 from Oracle Corporation at /CRM
2014-12-15 08:48:58,669 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] INFO  log.startup  - Starting: Using container abstraction org.directwebremoting.server.servlet3.Servlet30ContainerAbstraction
2014-12-15 08:48:58,703 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] INFO  servlet.UrlProcessor  - Probably not an issue: the url:/gi.js (org.directwebremoting.gi.GiHandler) Handler is not available. This is only an problem if you wanted to use it.
Error |
2014-12-15 08:48:58,878 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR util.LocalUtil  - Failed to load    'pageflow' (org.directwebremoting.beehive.PageFlowCreator)
Message: null
Line | Method
->> 1349 | classForName              in org.directwebremoting.util.LocalUtil
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     55 | addCreatorType            in org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultCreatorManager
|    192 | loadInits . . . . . . . . in org.directwebremoting.impl.DwrXmlConfigurator
|    161 | configure                 in     ''
|    597 | configureFromSystemDwrXml in org.directwebremoting.impl.StartupUtil
|    714 | configureContainerFully   in     ''
|    113 | configureContainer . . .  in org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet
|     72 | init                      in     ''
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassNotFoundException: Beehive/Weblogic jar file not available.
->>   57 | <init>                    in org.directwebremoting.beehive.PageFlowCreator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1349 | classForName              in org.directwebremoting.util.LocalUtil
|     55 | addCreatorType . . . . .  in org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultCreatorManager
|    192 | loadInits                 in org.directwebremoting.impl.DwrXmlConfigurator
|    161 | configure . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    597 | configureFromSystemDwrXml in org.directwebremoting.impl.StartupUtil
|    714 | configureContainerFully . in     ''
|    113 | configureContainer        in org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet
|     72 | init . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|   1142 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
```

Everything works properly, nothing breaks but this exception is polluting the logs. 
Anyone know what is it about and what should I do about it?

Comment: That appears to be a know issue with the plugin: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2991

Comment: got it. Im not using the plugin tho, but seems to be unresolved and ignored.

Comment: I see. If it's not directly related to the plugin that doesn't surprise me that there has been no movement on fixing it from the plugin perspective. You may want to reach out to the DWR developers to see if it's something they can resolve.